# Reading speaker output and convert to data

Tags: naudio

I am going to read the PC's music output and getting basic information (beat/tone/..) of the song played (then flash the lights accordingly etc). Can NAudio be used for the purpose and any samples? Sorry for this too general question at the moment.

TIA
-d

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access your PC's output using `WasapiLoopbackCapture`. However, NAudio does not include a beat detection algorithm, so you'd need to find one yourself. There is a FFT class though which could be used to determine frequencies present.